# Android theme naming reference

Tags: android

In res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
<style name="AppThem2" parent="@android:style/Theme"></style>
<style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme"></style>
```

AppTheme1 and AppTheme2 are correct, but why AppTheme3 is error?

Comment: Why not? What do you think "Theme" is pointing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no "Theme" ,you should add the path to help android find it.
"@android:style/Theme" is in the "styles" file
"Theme.AppCompat.Light" is in the "values" file